# How swiftUI implement drop to make navigationbar and background opacity change

Tags: swiftui, opacity, navigationbar

The ios files app for image detail view.When you drop down,the detail view image will scale and the navigationbar also the background opacity will change.Does any one have any idea if this feature can be implemented with pure SwiftUI code?Thanks.
[image]

I try to the follow way,but the detail view image will opacity will also change when drop down

```
Zstack{
            NavigationView{
                CellView
            }
            .zIndex(0)

            if showDetail{
                NavigationView{
                    detailView
                }
                .opacity(offsetProgress())
                .zIndex(1)
            }
        }
```